# Highlight custom node on mouse enter

Tags: infovis, thejit

I'm creating custom node and I would like to highlight on mouse enter. Unfortunately the `mouseEnter` event doesn't fire. I also don't know how to render the node after `mouseEnter` and `mouseLeave`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you written 'contains' function along with 'render' function in your custom node type definition? If you haven't then events like mouseEnter/onRightClick won't fire.

Here is the code having contains method for custom  node type.

```
$jit.ForceDirected.Plot.NodeTypes.implement({
 'icon1': { 
     'render': function(node, canvas){ 
                var ctx = canvas.getCtx(); 
                var img = new Image(); 
                img.src='magnify.png'; 
                var pos = node.pos.getc(true); 
                img.onload = function() { 
                        ctx.drawImage(img, pos.x, pos.y); 
                }; 

      }, 
        'contains': function(node,pos){ 
                var npos = node.pos.getc(true); 
                dim = node.getData('dim'); 
                return this.nodeHelper.circle.contains(npos, pos, dim);
                //return this.nodeHelper.square.contains(npos, pos, dim); 
      } 
  }
});
```